# Relative Pronoun Who/That in this sentence

Tags: grammar, pronouns, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

I've come across this type of sentence:

> I'm asking the name of person *was speaking to us.*

Could I use "That/Who" here? Like:

> [...] Of the person **who/that** *was talking to us*

Is it stuffy or grammatically incorrect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sentence you came across is incorrect. I suggest "I'm asking the name of ***the*** person ***who*** was speaking to us."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] Of the person who/that was talking to us

In this instance, use the relative pronoun 
**that** to link the essential clause.

In general, when referring to a person, use **who** or **whom** as the relative pronoun.  Also use **who** or **whom** when referring to an animal if it has a name and is seen as a person.  The possessive form **whose** can be used for persons, animals, or things.  Use of **that** as the relative pronoun can be used for persons, animals, or things with an essential clause.

Comment: I'm not sure why you suggest the OP uses "that" in their example. In general there is a preference for "who" when the relativised element is subject, as it is here. Incidentally, modern grammar rejects the analysis of relative "that" as a pronoun, sensibly preferring to analyse it as a subordinator.

Comment: The subject "person" in this instance is objective to the preposition "of".  The relativity here is "us" to whom "that" person was talking.  You are correct that "who" would be used in the subjective case.   Without the preposition, "who" would be relative to the subject of the sentence "The person who was talking to us."

Comment: Case is irrelevant. "Who" is subject of the relative clause. "I'm asking the name of the person [who was speaking to us]" is fine". "That" is possible too, but certainly not obligatory.

Comment: @BillJ ... Good point.  This conflict seems to be that our perspectives are a matter of interpretation.  I see "name" as the subject of the sentence and "speaking to us" as the relative clause  to "the person" requiring "that"; whereas you see "name of the person" as the subject which would require use of "who".  Thank you for pointing this out.